# How to scroll up in Vim buffer with R (using Nvim-R)

Tags: r, vim

I'm a happy user of the [Nvim-R](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R) plugin, but I cannot find out how to scroll up in the buffer window that the plugin opens with R. Say for instance that I have a large output in console, but I cannot see the top of it - how do I scroll up to see this? In tmux for instance there's a copy mode that quite handily lets you do this, but how is this done in the R buffer?

An example below where I'm very curious to see what's on the line above the one begining with "is.na(a)...". How can this be achieved?

I have scoured the documentation found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R/master/doc/Nvim-R.txt), but without luck.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is apparently to use <kbd>Ctrl+\ Ctrl+n</kbd> [according to this answer on the bugreports for NVim-R](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R/issues/336#issuecomment-398448042).

Here's what my output looks like when I output `mtcars`:

[image]

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl+\ Ctrl+n</kbd>, I can move the cursor and I get line numbers:

[image]

To get back to interactive, I just use `i`, the same way I normally would.

Apparently, if you are using neovim, then you can add `let R_esc_term = 0` in your `~/.vimrc` file and you can then use the escape key, but if you don't use neovim, you are stuck using the two ctrl commands ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, when I type Ctrl + \ in the Nvim-R buffer/split, I just get "7". Perhaps it is an issue with me being on a Danish keyboard, so will try to experiment with changing LocalLeader to something else than '\'...

Comment: Tried to remap LocalLeader to "," and then doing Ctrl + , Ctrl + n, but unfortunately still nothing, just in insert mode still

Comment: I hold ctrl down when i type both \ and n as opposed to releasing and pressing it a second time after \. Maybe that helps?

Comment: Hm, unfortunately not, tried both things. Releasing gets me just a backslash and holding gets me "7"...

Comment: I guess this is just some idiosyncrasy in my setup, as your solution works for most others, so I'll just accept your answer and continue to use the standalone R.app when I have to view R output above the fold :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [ZNK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51789334/9056440), it is about switching to normal mode in Vim's terminal. This, however, can easily fail due to cumbersome keybinding. If such is the case, remap the default keybinding to something reasonable, say, by putting this in your .vimrc:

`tnoremap jk <C-\><C-n>`

This works for me in Linux running Vim 8.0 in terminal (e.g. does not require Neovim). As you can see, I use 'jk' to switch from insert to normal mode. One can use Esc instead of jk, however, this makes me unable to use up arrow to retrieve command line history as been reported [elsewhere](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2716).